# How do I get Windows 7 driver automatically installed?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I would like my driver to automatically be detected by Windows 7 when the user connects my device, so all they need to do is connect the device (preferably not requiring administrator privileges).

I have a USB serial driver for Windows 7 and Windows 8.1. This is made up of a CAB and INF file, and is signed. The INF uses Microsoft's usbser.sys so I'm not installing a binary executable. It has my own VID and PID.

To install this at the moment, the user:

Downloads my driver and saves locally
Connects my device to a USB port
Opens device manager, and selects "Update Driver" on my device
Browses to my INF and CAB file
I can find information on how to get Windows 10 drivers distributed via Windows Update (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/publish-a-driver-to-windows-update), but nothing about Windows 7.

Does anyone have any guidance or advice on how to do this?

Comment: Maybe copy the drivers to where windows searches for them for new hardware....https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/where-setup-searches-for-drivers

Comment: So you're asking for help getting the driver for your device published by Microsoft via their update function. I believe that is not quite the sort of thing we can help you with here, and you should follow MS documentation regarding this process and contact them for assistance.

Comment: Also see this on how to add a driver...https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mspfe/2013/03/25/how-to-add-a-driver-to-the-driverstore/